# How to update a node using views module in drupal 7

Tags: json, rest, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to update couple fields of node using views module.If anyone knows then please tell me how i can do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For doing that you can use https://drupal.org/project/editableviews‎

here is a great tutorial for editableviews‎
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_D4z4Bw6iw

this module by adding editable views field allow you edit and update your fields from views.